# In Laravel, how to route GET and POST requests for the same pattern?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Is there a method to consolidate these two lines into a single line in Laravel 8?

```
Route::get('register', 'AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('register', 'AuthController@postLogin');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/register', AuthController@getAndPostLogin);
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#available-router-methods

Answer (score 0):

For a route, you can use the following syntax to aggregate all HTTP verbs:

Route::any('register', 'AuthController@login');